# Clarifications in Electric commander and tutorial

Tags: perl, build-process, electric-cloud

I was searching for tutorials on Electric cloud over the net but found nothing. Also could not find good blogs dealing with it. Can somebody point me in right directions for this?

Also we are planning on using Electric cloud for executing perl scripts in parallel. We are not going to build software. We are trying to test our hardware in parallel by executing the same perl script in parallel using electric commander. But I think Electric commander might not be the right tool given its cost. Can you suggest some of the pros and cons of using electric commander for this and any other feature which might be useful for our testing.

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RE #1:  All of the ElectricCommander documentation is located in the Electric Cloud Knowledge Base located at https://electriccloud.zendesk.com/entries/229369-documentation.

ElectricCommander can also be a valuable application to drive your tests in parallel.  Here are just a few aspects for consideration:

1. Subprocedures:  With EC, you can just take your existing scripts, drop them into a procedure definition and call that procedure multiple times (concurrently) in a single    procedure invocation.  If you want,     you can further decompose your     scripts into more granular subprocedures.  This will drive reuse,  lower cost of administration, and it will enable your procedures to run as fast as possible (see parallelism below).
2. Parallelism:  Enabling a script to run in parallel is literally as simple as checking a box within EC.  I'm not just referring to running 2 procedures at the same time without risk of data collision.  I'm referring to the ability to run multiple steps within a procedure concurrently.  Coupled with the subprocedure capability mentioned above, this enables your procedures to run as fast as possible as you can nest suprocedures within other subprocedures and enable everything to run in parallel where the tests will allow it.
3. Root-cause Analysis:  Tests can generate an immense amount of data, but often only the failures, warnings, etc. are relevant (tell me what's broken).  EC can be configured to look for very specific strings in your test output and will produce diagnostic based on that configuration.  So if your test produces a thousand lines of output, but only 5 lines reference errors, EC will automatically highlight those 5 lines for you.  This makes it much easier for developers to quickly identify root-cause analysis.
4. Results Tracking:  ElectricCommander's properties mechanism allows you to store any piece of information that you determine to be relevant.  These properties can be associated with any object in the system whether it be the procedure itself or the job that resulted from the invocation of a procedure.  Coupled with EC's reporting capabilities, this means that you can produce valuable metrics indicating your overall project health or throughput without any constraint.
5. Defect Tracking Integration:  With EC, you can automatically file bugs in your defect tracking system when tests fail or you can have EC create a "defect triage report" where developers/QA review the failures and denote which ones should be auto-filed by EC.  This eliminates redundant data entry and streamlines overall software development.

In short, EC will behave exactly they way you want it to.  It will not force you to change your process to fit the tool.  As far as cost goes, Electric Cloud provides a version known as ElectricCommander Workgroup Edition for cost-sensitive customers.  It is available for a small annual subscription fee and something that you may want to follow up on.

I hope this helps.  Feel free to contact your account manager or myself directly if you have additional questions (dfarhang@electric-cloud.com).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will check out the documentation and revert back for any clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could execute the same perl script on several machines by using r-commands, or cron, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

To further address the parallel aspect of your question:
The command-line interface lets you write scripts to construct
procedures, including this kind of subprocedure with parallel steps.
So you are not limited, in the number of parallel steps, to what you
wrote previously: you can write a procedure which dynamically sizes
itself to (for example) the number of steps you would like to run in
parallel, or the number of resources you have to run steps in
parallel.